# Does the function $f(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}$ have a name?

Tags: functions, terminology

Does the function $$f(x) = \frac{x}{\operatorname |x\ |}$$ have a common name in mathematics?

Comment: The signum function

Comment: This would give you the sign of $x$ which would be $\pm1$ assuming $x\ne0$. Sometimes written as $sgn(x)$ and is named the signum function which is actually defined as:$$sgn(x)=\begin{cases}-1&\text{ if }x\lt0\\0&\text{ if }x=0\\1&\text{ if }x\gt0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does exist and it has a name.

**Sign Function**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function

Comment: You make a subtle error. $\operatorname{sgn}(0)$ is defined. OP's function is not defined at $0$.

Comment: Side note: "does exist" is obvious (OP has just mentioned it in a question so it's "gotta exist").

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I think the OP didn't even know what to ask, so he just thought about this function for curiosity. In this way, he will learn more

Comment: I was discussing programming with a friend and was wondering what the correct name was as it seemed too simple to not already exist. 
Good catch on it being undefined at 0, it seems to differ by library on whether sign functions in programming return 1,0,-1 or 1,1,-1

I incorrectly assumed that the sign function in mathematics also mimic'd the return values of 1,1,-1 of the sign function in unity.